# How can I get <asp:menu> working in Safari?

Tags: safari, aspmenu

On the safari browser, the standard <asp:Menu> doesn't render well at all. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the advice, it led me into the following solution;

I created a file named "safari.browser" and placed it in the App_Browsers directory. The content of this file is shown below;

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="safari1plus">
        <controlAdapters>
            <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu" adapterType="" />
        </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

As I understand it, this tells ASP.NET not to use the adaptor it would normally use to render the control content and instead use uplevel rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ControlAdapters to alter the rendering of server controls.

Here's an example:
http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2007/03/27/46598.aspx

Though, in my opinion it might be equal amount of work to abandon the menu control for a pure css one (available on many sites).

Answer (score 0):

Oooof - was hoping it would be a simmple case of adding a browserCaps item in web.config with appropriate values or similar...

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest solution I've found for this problem is to include this bit of code in your page_load event.

```
if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0)
    Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear();
```